# Core Data and CLGeocoder

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am having problems to get this work , I using core data to fetch a list of  User ,

NSFetchrequets to extra the user location , List of Places and Postcode

[image]

```
NSFetchRequest *request =[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SiteLocation"]; //request all objects
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.srmDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

So I have a Entity "SiteLocation" loading the tableview with FetchedResultController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //NSLog(@"CELL");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Site Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    SiteLocation * siteLocation = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = siteLocation.siteName;

    return cell;
}
```

then I sent the selected row to the MapViewController  didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   NSLog(@"didselect sitePC");

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    UserDetails *userinfo = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.mapview.sitePC = userinfo; //sitePC is (id)
    NSLog(@"object selected= %@", userinfo);
} 
}

2012-10-04 13:27:46.401 SRMAB[459:c07] didselect sitePC = <SiteLocation: 0x1d80ad20> (entity: SiteLocation; id: 0x1d86b210 <x-coredata://523E1EB6-01DF-4889-B1A1-2E38E92D385E/SiteLocation/p120> ; data: {
    projectName =     (
        "0x1d82bc20 <x-coredata://523E1EB6-01DF-4889-B1A1-2E38E92D385E/UserDetails/p144>"
    );
    siteName = "Bloomberg Place 1";
    sitePostCode = "W1B 5AU";
})
```

On the MapViewController this will convert the sitePostcode to PlaceMark

```
-(void)myMapview
{
    NSLog(@"mymapview");

    NSString *addressString = [self.sitePC valueForKey:@"sitePostCode"];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *anError)
     {
         NSLog(@"Placemark count:%d",[placemarks count]);

         for(CLPlacemark *placemark1 in placemarks)
         {
             NSLog(@"Placemark: %@",placemark1);
             //[self displayPlacemarks:placemarks];
             CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
             zoomLocation.latitude = placemark1.location.coordinate.latitude;
             zoomLocation.longitude= placemark1.location.coordinate.longitude;

             MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 1000, 1000);
             MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapview regionThatFits:viewRegion];
             [self.mapview setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

             MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
             pa.coordinate = placemark1.location.coordinate;
             pa.title = [self.sitePC valueForKey:@"siteName"];
             [self.mapview addAnnotation:pa];
         }
```

I hope this make sense .

How can I Show all the location on the map when it loads ?

Question updated since the original question was a spelling mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `reason: '[<SiteLocation 0x1d80ad20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the
>   entity SiteLocation is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   "sitePostcode".'`

@"sitePostcode" is not the same as @"sitePostCode". You use the former in your call to `-valueForKey` in `-myMapView`, but the picture of your Core Data model shows the latter.

**Update:** To show a location on a map, you use a map annotation or overlay. For example, you can add a `MKPinAnnotation` to your map to indicate a position on the map. See [Annotating Maps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) for more information. I see that you're already using `MKPointAnnotation`, so it's not clear what your question is. Perhaps you're trying to show all the annotations at once -- if that's the problem, you'll just need to calculate the rectangle that bounds all your locations and zoom the map to include that area.

Comment: Haaaaaaaaaaaaa two day working on this ... 30 minutes writing this question all wasted ..... aaaa   thanks , can i ask something else  ..

Comment: question edited - How can Show all the location on the map when it loads .

Comment: I'll update my answer, but it's really better to create a separate question than to completely change the focus of an existing one.